# Does a file reported as "not a dynamic executable" by 'ldd' depend on other libraries?

Tags: compiling, shared-library

Just making sure I got this right - I call

```
ldd /path/to/executable
```

and it returns "not a dynamic executable". This means that it doesn't depend on other libraries, correct? If so, does it mean that it can be transferred to another Ubuntu box without worrying about dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, but there's something to take into account.

From the `ldd` manpage:

> ldd does not work on a.out shared libraries.
>
> ldd does not work with some extremely old  a.out  programs  which 
>   were built  before  ldd  support was added to the compiler releases. 
>   If you use ldd on one of these programs, the program will attempt to
>   run  with argc = 0 and the results will be unpredictable.

Comment: Another reason can be that the binary was built for 32-bit system but you're checking it on a 64-bit system.

Comment: @FerdinandPrantl If it's built for 32 bit, `ldd` still prints the 32bit dependencies.

Comment: @Calmarius that is not true, when you don't have basic 32-bit libgcc1. Just verified on a fresh Ubuntu Server installation: You need to install libgcc1:i386 to make ldd happy for 32-bit binaries.

Answer (score 1):

@Calmarius is correct, this happens if you consider a 32bit exe, without even basic 32bit libraries.

I'm attempting to upgrade my system (a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04, from 12.04), I have to install an old propitiatory 32bit service, `avserver`, that requires `ia32-libs` (no-longer available).  This means both `dpkg` and `apt-get` are unhappy (whatever I do, it prompts me to `apt-get -f install`, and if I run that, it insists I uninstall the service package), and my service won't start.

To prove that this is down to missing 32bit libraries, I have mounted my old system (Ubuntu 12.04, with `ia32-libs` and 32bit libraries) on `/sda2`.  Ensuring `/opt` (containing my 32bit binary) is mounted in `/sda2/opt`, I can `chroot /sda2` and `ldd` then runs as intended.

To fix this, I could have manually installed all the dependent library packages with :i386 (arch).  However I decided rather than try to figure out what my dependencies were, I installed wine (which is mostly 32bit, and so installs the basic libraries and a load more that I don't really need, but I'm ok with that).

To fix `dpkg` and `apt-get`, I edited `/var/lib/dpkg/status`, finding the package for my service, and removed `ia32-libs`.  Now `dpkg` and `apt-get` are happy

That done, `ldd` happily reports:-

`root@withnail:/opt/<service path># ldd avserver
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf77a6000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf778f000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7772000)
        libuuid.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0xf776b000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0xf7752000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0xf7720000)
        libktssl.so.1.0.0 => /opt/<service path>/libktssl.so.1.0.0 (0xf76cb000)
        libktcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /opt/<service path>/libktcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0xf756b000)
        libktz.so.1 => /opt/<service path>/libktz.so.1 (0xf7558000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf754f000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf73d8000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7383000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7366000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf71af000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x565b1000)`

Comment: Installing wine is a very clever trick for getting all the 32 bit libraries you need!!