# "No such file or directory" after chmod

Tags: command-line, permissions, chmod

I downloaded my professor's "shell" program and am trying to run it on my machine to do some homework. When I tried to run it from terminal using `./shell` I got a "Permission denied error". After running `chmod 777 shell` I tried runninging it again, only to get the "no such file or directory" error. I'm not sure why this is happening as I can still see the executable using `ls`. When I check the permissions of shell I get `-rwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu 9403 Feb 16 03:45 shell` so I'm not sure what the matter is. Can someone help me get this thing running?

Output of `file ./shell`:

```
./shell: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped
```

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux ubuntu 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Perhaps you are on a 64-bit system and the executable is a 32-bit one? In that case you need to install additional packages in order to run it.

Comment: @fkraiem - shell scripts are not 32 or 64 bit. compiled binaries will (usually) give ELF errors.

Comment: @muru I edited the posting, it's at the bottom.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen This is not a shell script. And, no.

Comment: @muru I added it

Comment: Giving global permissions isn't always the smartest thing to do. In fact it can actually break your system. Prefer `chmod +x`.

Comment: That output pretty much matches @fkraiem's original comment. To find out the missing libraries, run `ldd ./shell`  - some libraries may show up missing.

Comment: @muru I get the message "not a dynamic executable"

Comment: Going by [this comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/227671/does-a-file-reported-as-not-a-dynamic-executable-by-ldd-depend-on-other-libr#comment884473_227679), you might need to install `libgcc1:i386`.

Comment: The installation terminates with `E: Unable to locate package libgcc1
`

Comment: Well, if the issue was with 32 bit executable vs 64 bit system, it would complain about that wouldn't it ? But here we have existing file and yet it says file not found

Comment: @Serg That's because the error for a missing ELF interpreter is the same as that for a missing file. See [`man 2 execve`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/execve.2), look up `ENOENT`. So, if  `/lib/ld-linux.so` can't handle 32-bit executables, that's the error you'll get. Adam, try installing `gcc-multilib`.

Comment: @muru Got a whole bunch of fetch errors when I tried that one. I'm going to ask my professor about it, will post an answer if I get it running. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: ```ldd ./shell``` will show you whats missing...

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod +x <name of shell script>
```

is something you need to do to execute this shell script. What are the contents of the shell scripts. May be the "**no such file or directory**" error is coming from some command/action within the shell script. Please share the contents of the shell script or execute them one by one (one at a time) to find out which one is causing "no such file or directory" error.

Comment: I was just given an executable, the professor wants us to implement something similar by ourselves and so hasn't give us the source code.